# Check if at least one item in a group of items, is not empty

Tags: php

I have this kind of list of variables:

```
$item[1]['Value']
$item[2]['Value']
...
$item[50]['Value']
```

Some of them are `null`.

How do I check if at least one of them is not empty, and in this case, define that one (whether first case or last case) as a new variable?

P.S. What is the name of an `$var[number]['foo']` format? Is it an array?

Comment: What do you mean? If `$item[34]` is not empty, `$newOne = $item[34]` ? Is that it?

Comment: Loop through all and check is it empty or not if it is give an value?

Comment: @Lithilion Yes.

Comment: Please `print_r($item)` and show us the results or a part of the results where a few values are not empty and a few values are empty

Comment: not sure if looping is best solution, also the number of items is unknown, could be 1, could be 50, could be 100.

Comment: Use the answer of Goms and loop through the array

Comment: if it was just `$var[1]`, `$var[2]` , I think I could have used `in_array`, is there a way to do so when the format is `$var[1]['foo']` ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple test in using `empty()` function

```
if(!empty($item[$i]['value'])
{
    echo "exists";
}else{
   echo "is not set";
}
```

If you want affect a new value if it not exists or not defined, you can use `null coalescing operator`

```
$item[$i]['value'] = $item[$i]['value'] ?? $newvalue;
```

Comment: but `$i` is not defined.

Comment: but I don't know how many exists. there could be 50, and i just want to check if at least one is not empty and choose it.

Comment: Then, use @jasinth premkumar answer

Answer (score 0):

to check atleast one of them is not empty

```
<?php
   $atleast=0;//all are empty
   for($i=0;$i<count($item);$i++)
   {
     if(!empty($item[$i]['value']))
       $atleast=1;//one is empty;
   }
   if($atleast==1)
     echo "there is more than one element which are not empty";
   else
      echo "all are emtpy";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets the last found used element as `newVariable`.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($item); i ++)
{
 if(isset($item[$i]['Value']))
 {
  $newVariable = $item[$i]['Variable'];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) and use [`empty()`](https://php.net/empty) like this :

```
// example data
$items = [
    ['Value' => null],
    ['Value' => 2],
    ['Value' => null],
];

// remove elements with 'Value' = null
$filtered = array_filter($items, function($a) { return !is_null($a['Value']); }) ;

$element = null;
// If there is some values inside $filtered,
if (!empty($filtered)) {
    // get the first element
    $element = reset($filtered) ;
    // get its value
    $element = $element['Value'];
}

if ($element)
    echo $element ;
```

will outputs:

```
2
```

- [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) return an array with non-empty values (using use function).
- [`empty()`](https://php.net/empty) checks if an array is empty or not.
- [`reset()`](https://php.net/reset) gets the first element in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all the values of all items of the array you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

**Example**:

```
$item[1]['Value'] = "A";
$item[2]['Value'] = "B";
$item[4]['Value'] = "";
$item[3]['Value'] = NULL;


foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value['Value'])) {
        echo "$key It's not empty \n";
    } else {
        echo "$key It's empty \n";
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
1 It's not empty 
2 It's not empty 
3 It's empty 
4 It's empty
```

Also you can see that the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function consider NULL as empty.

**----- EDIT -----**

I forget to add the method to detect if at least one item it's empty, you can use:

**Example**

```
$item[1]['Value'] = "A";
$item[2]['Value'] = "B";
$item[4]['Value'] = "";
$item[3]['Value'] = NULL;


foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value['Value'])) {
        $item_result = false;
    } else {
        $item_result = true;
    }
}

if ($item_result) {
    echo "At least one item is empty";
} else {
    echo "All items have data";
}
```

**Result:**

```
At least one item is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the inner key as a variable name, then you can check whether you can create it and create it if so:

```
function any($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item) return $key;
    }
    return false;
}

$variableName = any($var);

if ($variableName !== false) {
    {$variableName} = "yourvalue";
} else {
    //We ran out of variable names
}
```

P.S. The format of `$var[number]['foo']` is an array with number keys on the outside and an array with string keys in the inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = 
[
    1  => ['foo' => ''],
    2  => ['bar' => 'big'],
    10 => ['foo' => 'fat']
];

$some_foo = function ($data) {
    foreach($data as $k => $v)
        if(!empty($v['foo'])) return true;

    return false;
};

var_dump($some_foo($data));
$data[10]['foo'] = null;
var_dump($some_foo($data));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Alternatively you can filter foo values that evaluate to false:

```
$some_foo = (bool) array_filter(array_column($data, 'foo'));
```